# Synchronous call not working but asynchronous does

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reference, synchronous

I have a simple method that works in an asynchronous format, but when I try to change it to a synchronous format, it acts like it deadlocks and never returns anything. I know it is more effective to use asynchronous calls but I am curious as to why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

This returns a working result:

```
public static async Task getCompanyAsync(){
    var client = new getRestClient();
    var response = await companiesApi.GetCompaniesAsync(client);
    var companies = response.GetResultAsync<List<Company>>();
}
```

This will make the program sit and spin until I kill it:

```
public static void getCompany(){
    var client = new getRestClient();
    var response = companiesApi.GetCompanies(client);
    var companies = response.GetResult<List<Company>>();
}
```

Edit:

So here is some more detailed code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        await getCompanyAsync();
        getCompany();
    }

    private static async Task getCompanyAsync()
    {
        var client = getApiClient();
        var companiesApi = new CompaniesApi(client);
        var response = await companiesApi.GetCompaniesAsync();
        var companyies = await response.GetResultAsync<List<Company>>();
        foreach (var company in companyies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
        }
    }

    private static void getCompany()
    {
        var client = getApiClient();
        var companiesApi = new CompaniesApi(client);
        var response = companiesApi.GetCompanies();
        var companyies = response.GetResult<List<Company>>();
        foreach (var company in companyies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
        }
```

I the application ran as expected when I moved `getCompany();` from the `MainAsync()` method into the `Main()` method.

Comment: This is problem of whatever library you are using. The code you are showing is not enough to see the problem.

Comment: Is this in a UI or a console application? (There may be differences in how async works in the different environments). Incidentally, the second code snippet shouldn't even compile because you're using "await" in a method that isn't async.

Comment: @EJoshuaS The await in the second snippet is a typo and I have now edited it out. This is running in a console application.

Comment: Are you using some kind of synchronization context?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your synchronous call at some point requires use of the same thread that is currently waiting on the synchronous call. E.g. you're in a GUI context and somewhere some code has tried to synchronously invoke a delegate on the UI thread. You can use a debugger and examine the state of the threads when the deadlock occurs, or you can post a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. No one is going to be able to pinpoint the exact problem with the little bit of code you've provided here.

Comment: See this article: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html and also this one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Is the main thread locking any variable that is supposed to be accessed by "var client = new getRestClient();" ? It could be a problem revolving around the main thread locking a variable and if not  accessed by the main thread its gets a dead lock.

Answer (score 0):

Two points here.

First, async will often work in unexpected ways in a console application (as compared to a UI application). This is because UIs have a "built in" synchronization contexts (and, obviously, because they don't automatically exit after their "main" method equivalent has completed execution), whereas Console applications don't. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) for directions on how to use a context in a console application to mitigate this.

Secondly, as pointed out in one of Stephen Cleary's excellent [articles](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on the topic, it's a bad practice to block on async if avoidable as it can lead to exactly the kinds of deadlocks you describe. Basically, one way of solving this is to use async "all the way down" - i.e. use async/await instead of GetResult() in your second sample. This idea is echoed in the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) of best practices for async, which recommend against mixing synchronous and asynchronous code like you do in the second code sample.

In the article I linked to the author explains how a deadlock can occur when you mix synchronous and asynchronous code. Basically, this can occur when, for example, the async method is waiting for the same context as the GetResults() call is. (His article explains it a lot better than me though :) ).